# Merge columns based on values in multiple columns pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a `DataFrame` as follows:

```
   Name  Col2        Col3
0  A     16-1-2000   NaN
1  B     13-2-2001   NaN
2  C     NaN         NaN
3  D     NaN         23-4-2014
4  X     NaN         NaN
5  Q     NaN         4-5-2009
```

I want to make a combined column based on either data of `Col2` & `Col3`, such it would give me following output.

```
   Name  Col2        Col3      Result
0  A     16-1-2000   NaN       16-1-2000
1  B     13-2-2001   NaN       13-2-2001
2  C     NaN         NaN       NaN
3  D     NaN         23-4-2014 23-4-2014
4  X     NaN         NaN       NaN
5  Q     NaN         4-5-2009  4-5-2009
```

I have tried following:

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df["Col2"].isnull() & df["Col3"].isnull(), np.nan, df["Col2"] if dfCrisiltemp["Col2"].notnull() else df["Col3"])
```

but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['new'] = df["Col2"].combine_first(df["Col3"])
#alternative
#df['new'] = df["Col2"].fillna(df["Col3"])
print (df)
  Name       Col2       Col3        new
0    A  16-1-2000        NaN  16-1-2000
1    B  13-2-2001        NaN  13-2-2001
2    C        NaN        NaN        NaN
3    D        NaN  23-4-2014  23-4-2014
4    X        NaN        NaN        NaN
5    Q        NaN   4-5-2009   4-5-2009
```

Your solution should be changed to another `np.where`:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df["Col2"].notnull() & df["Col3"].isnull(), df["Col2"],
            np.where(df["Col2"].isnull() & df["Col3"].notnull(), df["Col3"], np.nan))
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df["Col2"].notnull() & df["Col3"].isnull()
m2 = df["Col2"].isnull() & df["Col3"].notnull()
df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df["Col2"], df["Col3"]], np.nan)
```

For general solution filter all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), forward fill `NaN`s and last select last column:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Comment: Awesomme...Thanks for the answer. I was thinking about `numpy.select` and there you have it in your answer.